# I want to display the category and its child category structure on my page like below in magento 1.7

Tags: magento, categories

I'm new in magento and having problem with the category and its child category and their products structure .
plz can anyone give me the code to implement exactly the same structure .

I want structure like this on the content area ,not in the any side bar or header navigation :-

Main Category Name

Subcategory1 Name

```
  Product 1 
  Product 2
  .
  .
```

Subcategory2 Name

```
   Product 1 
   Product 2
   .
   .
```

and this should be work for every category.
Can anyone solve this ?
Thanks in advance :)

Answer (score 1):

Here is some code I have used to display sub category tiles on a category page.

https://www.evernote.com/shard/s4/sh/cc805407-a0d5-4d74-8cd2-b2d7513262f1/9934b5a9f09962b90fe5ecf76f06deb5

Answer (score 0):

I would suggests not to ask the for code better you try this people here can give idea.

Then also...
Go to following path in your magento(Note: Here I am using base/default/default you have to use in your template file).

/app/design/frontend/base/default/template/catalog/navigation

Create New file vert-navigation.phtml

```
<?php $_helper = Mage::helper('catalog/category') ?>
<?php $_categories = $_helper->getStoreCategories() ?>
<?php $currentCategory = Mage::registry('current_category') ?>
<?php if (count($_categories) > 0): ?>
 <div class="vertical-nav">
 <div class="navi-title"><h2>BROWSE BY CATEGORY</h2></div>
 <?php echo $this->getChildHtml('topSearch') ?>
    <ul>
        <?php foreach($_categories as $_category): ?>
            <li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a>
                <?php //if ($currentCategory->getName() == $_category->getName()): ?>
                    <?php $_category = Mage::getModel('catalog/category')->load($_category->getId()) ?>
                    <?php $_subcategories = $_category->getChildrenCategories();
                            //$count=0; ?>
                    <?php if (count($_subcategories) > 0): ?>
                    <!--li>
                <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_category) ?>">
                    <?php echo $_category->getName() ?>
                </a-->
                        <ul>
                            <?php foreach($_subcategories as $_subcategory): ?>
                                <li>
                                    <a href="<?php echo $_helper->getCategoryUrl($_subcategory) ?>">
                                        <?php echo $_subcategory->getName() ?>
                                    </a>
                                </li>
                                <?php //$count++; ?>
                                <?php //if($count==4) break; ?>
                            <?php endforeach; ?>
                        </ul>
                    <?php //endif; ?>
                <?php endif; ?>
            </li>
        <?php endforeach; ?>
    </ul>
<?php endif; ?>
</div>
```

Then go to /app/design/frontend/base/default/layout/catalog.xml place the below code

```
 <reference name="content">
        <!--block type="catalog/navigation" name="catalog.leftnav" after="currency" template="catalog/navigation/left.phtml"/-->
        <block type="catalog/navigation" before="-" name="catalog.vertnav" template="catalog/navigation/vert-navigation.phtml"/>
    </reference>
```

You will see the full listing of Category do style as you requirement.